# Wrangler publish fails because of exceeding size while gzip < 1mb

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

When I run wrangler publish, I get:

```
Total Upload: 2879.48 KiB / gzip: 474.38 KiB
```

The documentation mentions a maximum size of <1mb. The gzip is well below this threshold, yet I get the following error:

```
Script startup timed out. This could be due to script exceeding size limits or expensive code in 
the global scope. [code: 10021]
```

The odd thing is that it sometimes does upload the worker; but most of the time it fails with the above error message.

Answer (score 1):

This failure is due to the startup time limit of 200ms. It sounds like your code is spending more than 200ms to parse everything and execute the global scope. However, sometimes it stays under the limit due to random variation in timing.

This implies that your Worker will always experience cold start times around 200ms.

To fix this you should try to eliminate unneeded dependencies and unnecessary startup-time computation. Maybe there is work being done at startup that could be done lazily when needed by a request?